# Metric system not working properly while creating buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, buffer

I am creating 10 meter buffer on line geometry shapefiles.
But the output buffer is too large.

CRS of my shapefile is EPSG:24383, which is in metric system.
I am creating buffer using Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer

The units of buffer are shown correctly in meters. But the output buffer created is too large. May be 100 or 1000 times large. Or maybe more than that, I have no way to find it out.

I have tried MMQGIS plug-in also, but no different result.

Is there anything which I am missing out here.

Comment: what is EPSG:24384 ? I can't find it in QGIS nor in any EPSG lists ( https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/?search=24384&srtext=Search)

Comment: I assume it is in India as 24381, 24382 and 24383 are too. But 24384 doesn't seems to be recognized in QGIS so maybe the buffers are drawn in degrees and not meters as QGIS doesn't know the unit of this CRS. 
When you open your layer, does it overlap correctly with other layers that are in EPSG:4326 for instance (when On The Fly) ?

Comment: I am sorry. It’s 24383. I corrected it in question , It was a typo.

Comment: When I am creating buffer they are overlapping correctly. Only issue is that buffer is being created too large.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the correction :) in that case it looks like a unit problem. How large are the buffers? If they are drawn in degrees they would be 10 degrees so basically cover half of India, is it the case ? or is it a bit smaller ? (you can try to mesure them with the Mesure Tool)

Comment: Thanks, I am able to do that now. :)